# Performance Order By large table with Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, top

Hello I have a table with 206,902 records and I am struggling to improve my query:

```
SELECT TOP (50) [ID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Modified]
      ,[Created]
  FROM [Data]
 Inner Join [Permission]
    On ([Data].[ID] = [Permission].[FichaID]
   AND ([Permission].[PermID] = 1 AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 0
        OR [Permission].[PermID] IN (46, 50, 53) AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 1
        ))
Group By [ID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Modified]
      ,[Created]
   Order By [Created] desc
```

[image]

The query is running fast but using the tool SQLQueryStress with 50 iterations complement all time is 3 minutes.
If I remove the order by the query takes to run less than a second.
I have created an index on the table Data:

```
CREATE INDEX facervo_created ON [Data] ([Created] desc);
CREATE INDEX facervo_status ON [Data] ([_ModerationStatus]);
CREATE INDEX facervo_expiration ON [Data] ([Expiration]);
CREATE INDEX facervo_reserva ON [Data] ([Reserva]);
```

Index on the table Permission:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT perm_key PRIMARY KEY (FichaID, PermID, IsGroup)
```

Still not had great success in performance.
It is possible to execute this query faster?

### EDIT

I removed all the index of the two tables, and created this new index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_include1]
ON [Data]([Created] Desc)
INCLUDE ([ID]
        ,[Title]
        ,[Modified]);
```

Now this query taking 16 seconds, an evolution.
Is it possible to improve the most?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: Is that the only index on these tables?  A complete definition of any others may be informative, especially clustering definitions.

Comment: @MaxVernon is SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @MichaelGreen I updated the information in the index

Comment: How many rows in **both** tables?

Comment: @MartinSmith the table Data has 206902, and the table Permission has 827858

Comment: How many rows match the condition if you remove the `TOP 50`? With the `TOP 50` in place what is the actual vs estimated number of executions of the clustered index seek?

Comment: @MartinSmith Without top row is return: 58298. The index 'NCI1_included' Actual and Estimed Number Rows: 206902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just following on from @usr's answer (and similar question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/clustered-index-improvemens-for-particular-queries/82677#82677)), indexed views *could* work for this, or more (precisely a covering non-clustered index on the index view), as long as you're aware they can destroy `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` performance on the underlying tables and (from experience) can contribute to deadlocks.

If neither table is that dynamic though, (and assuming the ID column is unique), you could create view which has the same criteria as your query (minus the `TOP` and `ORDER BY`), create a unique clustered index on the view's ID column, then a non-clustered index on 'Create DESC', including 'Title' and 'Modified'.  I've created a simple rig to demonstrate this.  Work through it and see this approach could work for you:

```
USE tempdb
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

/*
SELECT TOP (50) [ID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Modified]
      ,[Created]
  FROM dbo.[Data]
 Inner Join dbo.[Permission]
    On ([Data].[ID] = [Permission].[FichaID]
   AND ([Permission].[PermID] = 1 AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 0
        OR [Permission].[PermID] IN (46, 50, 53) AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 1
        ))
Group By [ID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Modified]
      ,[Created]
   Order By [Created] desc
*/

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Setup START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.vw_permission_data') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW dbo.vw_permission_data
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Data
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Data (
    ID                  INT NOT NULL,
    Title               VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PermID              INT NOT NULL,
    IsGroup             BIT NOT NULL,
    Created             DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Modified            DATETIME NULL,
    _ModerationStatus   INT NULL,
    Expiration          DATETIME NULL,
    Reserva             DATETIME NULL,
    FichaID             INT NOT NULL,

)
GO


IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Permission') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Permission
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Permission (
    PermID              INT NOT NULL,  
    IsGroup             BIT NOT NULL,
    FichaID             INT NOT NULL,
)
GO

--CREATE INDEX facervo_created ON [Data] ([Created] desc);
--CREATE INDEX facervo_status ON [Data] ([_ModerationStatus]);
--CREATE INDEX facervo_expiration ON [Data] ([Expiration]);
--CREATE INDEX facervo_reserva ON [Data] ([Reserva]);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Permission ADD CONSTRAINT perm_key PRIMARY KEY ( FichaID, PermID, IsGroup )
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_include1]
ON [Data]([Created] Desc)
INCLUDE ([ID]
        ,[Title]
        ,[Modified]);
GO

-- Add dummy data
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT TOP 206902 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) rn
FROM master.sys.columns c1
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c2
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c3
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Data ( ID, Title, PermID, IsGroup, Created, Modified, _ModerationStatus, Expiration, Reserva, FichaID )
SELECT rn ID, NEWID() Title, rn % 33 PermID, rn % 7 IsGroup, DATEADD( day, rn % 300, '1 Jan 2014' ) Created, NULL Modified, rn % 33 _ModerationStatus, NULL Expiration, NULL Reserva, rn FichaID
FROM cte
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Permission ( PermID, IsGroup, FichaID )
SELECT DISTINCT 1, IsGroup, FichaID
FROM dbo.Data
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT TOP 4 1 x FROM dbo.Data ) x
GO 

-- Setup END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Original Queries START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT TOP (50) [ID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Modified]
      ,[Created]
  FROM dbo.[Data]
 Inner Join dbo.[Permission]
    On ([Data].[ID] = [Permission].[FichaID]
   AND ([Permission].[PermID] = 1 AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 0
        OR [Permission].[PermID] IN (46, 50, 53) AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 1
        ))
Group By [ID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Modified]
      ,[Created]
Order By [Created] desc
GO

-- Original Queries END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Indexed Views START
-- with supporting non-clustered indexes
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.vw_permission_data') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW dbo.vw_permission_data
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_permission_data
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
     [ID]
    ,[Title]
    ,[Modified]
    ,[Created]
 FROM dbo.[Data]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Permission] ON ([Data].[ID] = [Permission].[FichaID]
   AND ([Permission].[PermID] = 1 AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 0
        OR [Permission].[PermID] IN (46, 50, 53) AND [Permission].[IsGroup] = 1
    ))
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_vw_permission_data ON dbo.vw_permission_data ( ID )
GO

CREATE INDEX idx_vw_permission_data1 ON dbo.vw_permission_data ( [Created] DESC )
INCLUDE ( Title, Modified )
GO

-- Indexed Views END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Revised Query START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT TOP 50 
     [ID]
    ,[Title]
    ,[Modified]
    ,[Created]
FROM dbo.vw_permission_data
ORDER BY Created DESC

-- Revised Query END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You could also create a single unique clustered index on ( `Created DESC`, `ID` ).  The query on the indexed view dramatically reduced the reads and runtime in my rig, but I would say both queries were running 77 and 0 milliseconds respectively on my laptop, so really quick:

[image]

These are relatively low numbers of records (200k and 800k), so it's a bit of a mystery as to why your query is taking 16 seconds!?  Have you checked for blocking?  Is the system very busy?

Comment: With one iteration of the query taking a second to load, now with 50 iterations to query this lingering 16 seconds to load. These tests were performed by SQLQueryStress tool

Comment: Well there must be something else going on here.  Can you confirm the specs of the box you are working on, OS, CPUs, RAM and the SQL Server edition ( eg `SELECT @@version` ).

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) CPU: I7 16GB Ram

Comment: Hello I changed the query in code view by adding the WITH (NOEXPAND).
In this way the query using the index and is now returned in less than a second. 

SELECT TOP 50 
     [ID]
    ,[Title]
    ,[Modified]
    ,[Created]
FROM dbo.vw_permission_data WITH ( NOEXPAND )
ORDER BY Created DESC

Comment: Good new @Tiago.  The `NOEXPAND` hint is required to use indexed views in non-Enterprise editions.  How long does your complete stress test take now?  Remember the effect on `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` operations indexed views can cause.  Consider dropping them before loading the table.  Also as a best practice, you should consider upgrading your SQL Server to the latest patch level, SQL 2008 R2 is now at SP3, available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527041).

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic performance problem. You are ordering on the columns of one table and are filtering on the columns of another.

SQL Server can either scan `Data` and filter out rows by seeking into the other table (the current plan). Or it can access `Permission` to determine the `Data` rows that pass the filter, and then sort this set. Both plans require a lot of data to be touched because the filter is too selective for plan 1 and to little selective for plan 2.

There is no index that is able to cover both the sort and the filter because the columns belong to different tables.

Consider creating an indexed view that contains all the columns used here. This will result in near-perfect performance because you can now index all required columns.

Or, denormalize your data model. Store permission information directly in the `Data` table.

Comment: I thought I would change my data model for recording all the information in the table Data.
The only question in this model is that I have to record multiple IDs in a single column, it will be not bad for the SQL to perform the filter?

Comment: The filter will not be SARGable, that's all. This is generally an anti-pattern. Your case is a valid use case. You can use XML (indeed very CPU heavy) or string "hacks" like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause/337817#337817, or some SQL CLR stuff.